# iPhone Screen Capturing Question

Tags: iphone

I'm writing an iPhone App that allows people to share images that may be copyrighted(not illegally).  The issue I am having is that I'm looking for a way to work around the screen capturing.  Is there any possible way you can disable screen capturing or possibly distort the image in some way so capturing will be useless, maybe even block the images when a screen capture is trying to be taken?

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible because it is embedded in iOS itself. Maybe some private APIs, but then there is no app store for your app.

Comment: To add to that, iOS's public methods don't allow for that level of OS access.

Answer (score 1):

Watermarking the images may be a good half-way solution.

Answer (score -1):

iOS screen capture does not support capturing everything. It does not capture OpenGL or YouTube for example. So if you can manage to implement showing images using OpenGL instead of the simple way using UIKit they would not show up on a screen shot.

Comment: Are we talking about the same os?? I can capture screen-shots (press the sleep-wake button and home button at the same time) in the youtube app... Also in OpenGL games.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm if you can do a screen capture with an OpenGL app?

Comment: I just tested it with Zen Bound, which is definitely using OpenGL ES 2.0 on my 3GS and did several screen captures with no trouble whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, seems this changed recently. Source of my information was an Apple document <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html> plus I tested you cannot capture a YouTube screenshot using the buttons on iPhone4 iOS 4.1. Well, obviously you should not rely on side-effects since they might change with new OS versions.